# How to change case of matching letter with a VBA regex Replace?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a column of lists of codes like the following.

```
2.A.B, 1.C.D, A.21.C.D, 1.C.D.11.C.D
6.A.A.5.F.A, 2.B.C.H.1
8.ABC.B, A.B.C.D
12.E.A, 3.NO.T
A.3.B.C.x, 1.N.N.9.J.K
```

I want to find all instances of two single upper-case letters separated by a period, but only those that follow a number less than 6. I want to remove the period between the letters and convert the second letter to lower case. Desired output:

```
2.Ab, 1.Cd, A.21.C.D, 1.Cd.11.C.D
6.A.A.5.Fa, 2.Bc.H.1
8.ABC.B, A.B.C.D
12.E.A, 3.NO.T
A.3.Bc.x, 1.Nn.9.J.K
```

I have the following code in VBA.

```
Sub fixBlah()
Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "\b([1-5]\.[A-Z])\.([A-Z])\b"
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    c.Value = re.Replace("$1$2")
Next c
End Sub
```

This removes the period, but doesn't handle the lower-case requirement. I know in other flavors of regular expressions, I can use something like

```
re.Replace("$1\L$2\E")
```

but this does not have the desired effect in VBA. I tried googling for this functionality, but I wasn't able to find anything. Is there a way to do this with a simple `re.Replace()` statement in VBA?

If not, how would I go about achieving this otherwise? The pattern matching is complex enough that I don't even want to think about doing this without regular expressions.

[I have a solution I worked up, posted below, but I'm hoping someone can come up with something simpler.]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that uses the properties of each individual regex match to make the VBA `Replace()` function replace only the text from the match and nothing else.

```
Sub fixBlah2()
Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
Dim M As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
Dim tmpChr As String, pre As String, i As Integer
Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "\b([1-5]\.[A-Z])\.([A-Z])\b"
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    'Count of number of replacements made. This is used to adjust M.FirstIndex
    '    so that it still matches correct substring even after substitutions.
    i = 0
    Set Matches = re.Execute(c.Value)
    For Each M In Matches
        tmpChr = LCase(M.SubMatches.Item(1))
        If M.FirstIndex > 0 Then
            pre = Left(c.Value, M.FirstIndex - i)
        Else
            pre = ""
        End If
        c.Value = pre & Replace(c.Value, M.Value, M.SubMatches.Item(0) & tmpChr, _ 
                  M.FirstIndex + 1 - i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Next M
Next c
End Sub
```

For reasons I don't quite understand, if you specify a start index in `Replace()`, the output starts at that index as well, so the `pre` variable is used to capture the first part of the string that gets clipped off by the `Replace` function.

Answer (score 1):

So this question is old, but I do have another workaround.  I use a double regex so to speak, where the first engine looks for the match as an execute, then I loop through each of those items and replace with a lowercase version.  For example:

```
Sub fixBlah()
Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
dim ToReplace as Object
Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
for each c in Selection.Cells
with re      `enter code here`
  .Global = True
  .Pattern = "\b([1-5]\.[A-Z])\.([A-Z])\b"
  Set ToReplace = .execute(C.Value)
end with

 'This generates a list of items that match.  Now to lowercase them and replace
 Dim LcaseVersion as string
 Dim ItemCt as integer
 for itemct = 0 to ToReplace.count - 1
 LcaseVersion = lcase(ToReplace.item(itemct))
      with re      `enter code here`
  .Global = True
  .Pattern = ToReplace.item(itemct)  'This looks for that specific item and replaces it with the lowercase version
  c.value = .replace(C.Value, LCaseVersion)
end with
End Sub
```

I hope this helps!